# Building opencv 3.1 on windows - where do I specify the LAPACK library location?

Tags: opencv, build, cmake, lapack

For building opencv 3.1 I'm using cmake with Visual Studio 2013. I downloaded the dependencies as shown here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html
While configuring cmake, the first thing it shows is:

```
FP16: Compiler support is available
A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
```

The problem is, that I don't know how to specify the location. For the "Eigen" library I set the library path myself (EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH, which is pre defined) and cmake says:

```
Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.10)
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO
```

but there is no pre defined variable for LAPACK. I also tried to put the *.lib and header files in a subdirectory, which I downloaded from http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/, in the hope if cmake somehow finding the library.

I have to build opencv 3.1 myself, because in the distributed version, the extra modules are disabled. It builds without LAPACK, but my guess is, that I will loose a lot of performance.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/39126731/2799037 or https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html

Comment: This solved it for me. It's for Linux, but same concept worked on Wndows: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12957  .

1) I installed OpenBLAS from here:https://www.openblas.net/  .

2) I edited the OpenCVFindOpenBLAS.cmake file inside the {opencv_source _dir}}/cmake folder, by adding the lib and include directories of OpenBLAS in the respective places  .

After that CMake was able to find OpenBLAS and the Lapack library coming with it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I used [OpenBlas](http://www.openblas.net/) library:

Use CMake Gui to config `opencv`

- Select `Advanced`
- In the `OpenBLAS` group, config the include folder and library file for `OpenBLAS`
- In the `WITH` group, select `WITH_LAPACK`
- Now click the `Configure` button, CMake will automatically config Lapack info.
- After all is ok, you can click on `Generate` button on CMake Gui to generate visual studio project files and start to build.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a comment but I do not have enough rep for it. 
In my case to build OpenCV 3.2 in Visual Studio 2013 with `OpenBlas` and `LAPACK`, in addition to Viets' answer, I had to change two lines in `lapacke.h` to use the standard library based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853450/errors-using-lapack-c-header-in-c-with-visual-studio-2010)

So, for OpenBLAS version 0.2.19-Win64-int32 in `lapacke.h` I changed

@line 74 `float _Complex` to `std::complex<float>` and

@line 90 `double _Complex` to `std::complex<double>`

without the need to build the OpenBLAS library again.

Hope it helps.